# Cant install LightGBM on Macbook Pro M1 2020, It doesnt seem to recognize Cmake

Tags: macos, cmake, pip, apple-m1, lightgbm

MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
macOS Monterey 12.6

When I try to install LightGBM (via pip) I get the error:
Exception: Please install CMake and all required dependencies first

I already tried installing it via brew as well and it didnt work

I went through a few different tutorials in the web where you clone a directory from somewhere and build it from there but i ran into different errors there as well.

Has anyone had a similar experience and an idea what to do?

Comment: news about this?

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia i got around pip by using conda, dont know if the answer of yaron works, cant try it out atm

Answer (score 1):

I tried many things, but none of them worked. It worked only after using the code below.

```
 pip install lightgbm --install-option=--nomp
```

Hope it will work for you as well

Comment: Hey, I worked around it already by using conda and not pip to install it, but thanks for the answer. If I should have the problem in the future again ill try it